# ResourceExhaustError on Tensorflow, cannot switch to CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error when running the example code from the website below on GPU
I have an Nvidia 1030 in my work PC which only has 2gm of memory
I have 16gm of RAM

The GPU memory error is understandable, which is why I am trying to switch to CPU
I was suggested to use this code, but it doesn't work and its still failing on the same error

Whats the proper way to force tensorfow to use regular ram?
Is there any way to get Tensorflow to use less memory or to manage memory better?

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID" 
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""
```

...

```
Exception has occurred: ResourceExhaustedError
 OOM when allocating tensor with shape[16,128,161,161] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node Conv2DBackpropInput_3 (defined at c:\Dev\Projects\TooGAN\Dataset\gan_test.py:147) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_on_batch_1575]

Function call stack:
train_on_batch
  File "C:\Dev\Projects\TooGAN\Dataset\gan_test.py", line 147, in train
    d_loss1, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real)
  File "C:\Dev\Projects\TooGAN\Dataset\gan_test.py", line 211, in <module>
    train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim)
```

Comment: Try `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'`

Comment: Setting the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES needs to be done before importing TensorFlow, are you doing it that way?

Comment: if you still want to use your GPU have you tried reducing the batch size for training. The smaller the batch size the less GPU memory is required.